# Floating Header not aligning with table contents on Window Resize (HTML/CSS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a table that has the header stay at the top of the screen when scrolling down the table. The problem that I am facing is that when I resize the window to a width that squishes down the header, when I scroll down, it goes back to its original width. This results in columns and headers that don't line up with each other. Here is a picture to better illustrate my problem:

[image]

In addition, I have am trying to add a background color to the header, but it disappears when I begin to scroll.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<!--website main heading layout-->
<div id="heading">
    <h1> Beat Your Pace <h1/>
    <h2> The music search tool to boost your running performance! </h2>
</div>



<!--topbar/menu layout-->
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="topbar_wrapper">
        <ul id="mainmenu">
            <li><a href="beat_your_pace.php">Home</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Search</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Sort By &#9660</a>
                <ul id="sortmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>Song</a>
                        <ul id="songsortmenu" class="sortsubmenu">
                            <li><a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=name_a'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                            <a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=name_z'>Z to A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li>   
                    <a href='#'>Artist</a>
                        <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                            <li><a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=artist_a'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                            <a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=artist_z'>Z to A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Album</a>
                        <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                            <li><a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=album_a'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                            <a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=album_z'>Z to A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li>   
                    <a href='#'>Genre</a>
                        <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                            <li><a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=genre_a'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                            <a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=genre_z'>Z to A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li>
                    <a href='#'>BPM</a>
                        <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                            <li><a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=bpm_slow'>Slowest to Fastest</a></li><li>
                            <a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=bpm_fast'>Fastest to Slowest</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Release Date</a>
                        <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                            <li><a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=rd_new'>Newest to Oldest</a></li><li>
                            <a href='beat_your_pace.php?sort=rd_old'>Oldest to Newest</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a href='song_info_entry.html'>Add Song</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- MySQL/PHP/HTML database song table layout-->
<?php
// Get a connection for the database
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

// Create a query for the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM song";

//decide how to sort table]
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    if ($_GET['sort'] == 'name_a'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY name ASC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'name_z'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY name DESC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'artist_a'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY artist ASC";
    }
    elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'arist_z'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY artist DESC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'album_a'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY album ASC";
    }
    elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'album_z'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY album DESC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'genre_a'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY genre ASC";
    }
    elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'genre_z'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY genre DESC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'bpm_slow'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY bpm ASC";
    }
    elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'bpm_fast'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY bpm DESC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'rd_new'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY release_date DESC";
    }
    elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'rd_old'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY release_date ASC";
    }
}


// Get a response from the database by sending the connection
// and the query
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

// If the query executed properly proceed
if($response){
    echo '
    <table id="maintable" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>Name</b></th>
                <th><b>Artist</b></th>
                <th><b>Album</b></th>
                <th><b>Genre</b></th>
                <th><b>Release Date</b></th>
                <th><b>BPM</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>';

    // mysqli_fetch_array will return a row of data from the query
    // until no further data is available
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
        echo '<tbody>
                <tr>

        <td>' . $row['name'] . 
            '</td><td>' . $row['artist'] . 
            '</td><td>' . $row['album'] . 
            '</td><td>' . $row['genre'] .
            '</td><td>' . $row['release_date'] . 
            '</td><td>' . $row['bpm'] . '</td><td align="left">';

        echo '  </tr>
            </tbody>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
} 
else {
    echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
    echo mysqli_error($dbc);
}

// Close connection to the database
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>





<!--script for sticky table header-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.sticky.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            $('tr:even>td').addClass('alt');
            $("#maintable").sticky();
        })();
    </script>
```

CSS Code for Table:

```
table {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

table > thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
}
table tr td {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't repeat tbody in your while loop. It's supposed to wrap all table rows.

Comment: Is there more to the css or a javascript that changes the thead style? I see you mentioned the header stays on scroll, I don't see how it would using the css you provided.

Comment: It does so using a jquery library

Comment: I see now, it's stickyjs if I'm not mistaken. I see this getWidthFrom option in its readme: https://github.com/garand/sticky